# React form is putting text field values into query strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

For some reason upon clicking the submit button on a login form in my React tutorial, the URL changes from domain.com/login to domain.com/login?email=max%40test.com&password=admin123 putting the email and password field into the URL.

The instructor's example doesn't seem to do this.

```
LoginScreen.js

import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { loginAction } from '../state/actions/userActions'


const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPW] = useState('')
    const location = useLocation()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const submitLoginHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(loginAction(email, password))
    }

    return (
        <div className="full-container w-full">
            <div className="login-content-container max-w-5xl mx-auto p-16 my-8">
                <div className="login-container flex items-center bg-white shadow-2xl rounded-md overflow-hidden">
                    <div className="form-container rounded-md p-8 my-16">
                        <h2 className="my-1 font-medium text-center text-2xl">sevenTwigs</h2>
                        <span className="mb-8 block text-center font-light text-md">Account Login</span>
                        <form className="login-form p-4">
                            <div className="input-group flex flex-col items-center">
                                <input 
                                    className="email-input border-2 border-gray-200 placeholder-gray-400 rounded-md px-4 py-2 m-2 w-full text-sm font-light" 
                                    type="email" 
                                    name="email" 
                                    placeholder="Enter your email"  
                                    value={email} 
                                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />    
                                <input 
                                    className="password-input border-2 border-gray-200 placeholder-gray-400 rounded-md px-4 py-2 m-2 w-full text-sm font-light" 
                                    type="password" 
                                    name="password" 
                                    placeholder="Your password"
                                    value={password} 
                                    onChange={(e) => setPW(e.target.value)} />    
                                <button
                                    type="submit" 
                                    className="w-full rounded-sm px-4 py-2 bg-pink-400 hover:bg-pink-300 hover:shadow-md disabled:bg-gray-400 
                                    text-white shadow-sm text-center text-sm my-4"
                                    value="submit" 
                                    onClick={(e) => submitLoginHandler(e)} >
                                    LOG IN
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div className="new-user-register text-sm text-center text-gray-400">
                            Don't have an account? 
                            <Link to="/register/" className="text-gray-500"> Register</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-splash-image bg-black w-2/3 hidden md:flex">
                        <img src="/images/wallpainting.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

```
app.js
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen'
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen'
import CheckoutScreen from './screens/CheckoutScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <div className="main-content h-full min-h-screen flex" style={{backgroundColor: '#f5fcf7'}}>
          <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
          <Route path="/products/:id" component={ProductScreen}  />
          <Route path="/cart" component={CartScreen} />
          <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutScreen} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Backend Express Routes

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { userAuth, registerUser, retrieveProfile } = require('../controller/userController')
const { protect } = require('../middleware/authTokenMW')


router.post('/login', userAuth)
router.post('/register', registerUser)
router.route('/profile')
    .get(protect, retrieveProfile)


module.exports = router
```

```
server.js
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const products = require ('./data/products')
const productRoutes = require('./routes/productRoutes')
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes')
const { notFound, errorHandler } = require('./middleware/errorHandlerMW')

const app = express()
dotenv.config()
connectDB()
app.use(express.json())

// Start Server
app.listen(5000, () =>{
    console.log('Server started')
})

// Route for Products
app.use('/api/products', productRoutes)

// Route for Users
app.use('/api/users/', userRoutes)


// Error Handlers
app.use(notFound)
app.use(errorHandler)
```

Is putting text field values into query strings in the URL done by React on default? Or did I mess with something inadvertently?

Comment: What’s the code in login action?

Comment: I figured out how to solve it. But not why it was doing it.

I had onClick on the form button. Instead it should have been onSubmit and moved to the form tag and not the button tag.

Doing this made it so the submit works properly and the URL doesn't change.

Does anyone know why using onClick on the button would cause query strings to appear in the URL?

Comment: When your button is of type="submit" your form is submitted with a method="GET" which attaches those query strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button is of type submit and you have not specified any properties for the form. So by default, it is going to assume a few things,

**method="Get"** and
**action="Your URL"**

So it adds all params to your URL as query string params.

And adding the submit event to the form will solve the issue as you have `e.preventDefault` there.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass event as a parameter on function call, the e.preventDefault() will not work.

Try to use just

```
onClick={submitLoginHandler}
```

instead of

```
onClick={(e) => submitLoginHandler(e)}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. Removing the ()=> from onClick will cause the function to run right when the component loads. Removing the e will not allow e.preventDefault() to work.

Comment: Actually it just calls the function when you use '( )' after it. If you use the first way I showed, the function will only be called at the click of the button.
The 'event' is a default parameter, so, you don't need to specify it at the function call